# Android Studio: Gradle Sync fail with v4 support library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, gradle, android-support-library

I have been following the Android fragments tutorial which requests that I set up my project to work with the v4 library by following the Support Library Setup document [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

Here are the steps I followed.

> 1) Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using
>   the SDK Manager.
>
> 2) Open the build.gradle file for your application.
>
> 3) Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example,
>   to add the v4 support library, add the following lines:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     ...
>     compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"
> }
> ```

After following the three steps I receive these two errors:

`Gradle project sync failed...`

```
Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

According to the Android SDK Manager, I do have the Android Support Repository installed.

I am going to continue investigating this issue as fragments appear to be a valuable tool to develop powerful Android mobile apps. Help approaching this issue would be appreciated.

As Sufian requested in the comments below, here are the contents of my build.gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPDXS.jpg) of my Android Standalone SDK Manager showing that the Android Support Repository is installed.

Comment: "According to the Android SDK Manager, I do have the Android Support Repository installed." Have you tried downloading/installing it then?

Comment: Also post your build.gradle file.

Comment: @Sufian I updated my post to include the build.gradle file and a screenshot of my Android Support Repository installation.

Comment: RTFM: `// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two build.gradle files in your project, one rootlevel, and one for your application. You will also see a dependencies section in the other build.gradle. You need to place the `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"` in there.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"` in `<PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle` instead you should add the above dependency in `<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle`